# How to print Array size in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using **Thymeleaf** with **spring mvc 4** but I have a problem when I want to print a list size

```html
<tr th:each="u : ${users}" th:id="${u.username}" class="odd gradeX">
    <th></th>
    <td th:text="${u.username}"></td>
    <td th:text="${u.email}"></td>
    <td th:switch="${u.enabled}">
        <span th:case="true" class="badge badge-primary">Acitf</span>
        <span th:case="false" class="badge badge-danger">Désactivée</span>
        <span th:case="*" class="badge badge-dark">Inconnue</span>
    </td>
    <td th:switch="${u.roles}">
        <span th:case="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN">Super ADmin</span>
        <span th:case="ROLE_MANGER">Manager</span>
        <span th:case="ROLE_SUPERVISEUR">Superviseur</span>
        <span th:case="ROLE_USER">User</span>
        <span th:case="*">Inconnue</span>

    </td>
    <td th:text="${#calendars.format(u.creationDate,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')}"></td>
    <td th:text="${#calendars.format(u.lastLogin,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')}"></td>
    **
    <td th:text="${u.engines}"></td>
    <td th:text="${u.subordonnes}"></td>
    **
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

the problem is here `th:text="${u.engines}</td>`. `engines` is an ArrayList in my `User` entity. I tried `th:size` and `th:list` but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me please

### Edited

here is my `User` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "superieur")
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> subordonnes = new ArrayList<User>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_ENGINES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "NUM_EQUIPMENT"))
@JsonIgnore
private List<Engine> engines = new ArrayList<Engine>();
```

and my Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/listeUsers"})
public ModelAndView userlistePage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    User logedUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users = userService.findUserSub(logedUser);
    model.addObject("users", users);
    model.setViewName("utilisateur/list_users");
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Did `u.engines.size()` not work?

Comment: no it didn't work either

Comment: Can you add your controller/context and model code?

Comment: @Charlie here is my controller code and where i declared the lists

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Did you get an error? If you attach a debugger or log the engines object, what does it say is inside? Does it have a size?

Comment: u.engines.size() really should have worked; can you try it again and update the code to reflect what you tried?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try using the utility method for `org.thymeleaf.expression.Lists`:

```
<td th:text="${#lists.size(u.engines)}">[Engine Size]</td>
```

Comment: how to get size of inner objects?

Comment: Did you try u.engines.someInnerObjectName ?

Comment: Docs links for reference are here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#lists and here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.13.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Lists.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides the util method [vphilipnyc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43485872/7082956) described, instead of list.size, use list.size().

When writing list.size, it's trying to call list.getSize() and an List (or a collection) doesn't have a getter named like this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to make use of length property

Example Snippet written below

```
<p id="clientCountTracker" style="display: block"
                        th:text="${contentDTO.clients.length}"
                        ></p>
```

Where "client" is an array

Comment: OP has a List though