# Spring boot and thymeleaf: Can not evaluate size() of an ArrayList

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have an ArrayList in my mvc controller class:

```
List<Market> markets = loadMarkets();
```

I add this list to Model object:

```
model.addAttribute("markets", markets);
```

In my template, when I want to get size() of this array:

```
<span>Top <strong th:text="${markets.size}"></strong>assets.</span>
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): The method size() is undefined for the type Object.
```

Snapshot of the VSCode debugging tools:

[image]

I am using Spring Boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE with Thymeleaf template engine.

Comment: According to your error message you have a Java code compilation error: ``model.getAttribute("markets").size()` - not a Thymeleaf expression evaluation error. You can't find the `size()` of an `Object` (which is what you get returned from the `getAttribute()` method). Comment out (or delete) that line of Java code and try again. See if you get a different error - or no error at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Array size in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484142/how-to-print-array-size-in-thymeleaf) note says array size, but is about array lists. There is utility methods in thymeleaf for this

Comment: Just to clarify: The Thymeleaf expression in the question works as written: `th:text="${markets.size}"`. Yes, there are Thymeleaf utility objects - such as this: `th:text="${#lists.size(markets)}"` - but I don't think this is needed here. It's the Java code which needs to be fixed (or removed, if not needed).

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are using `size` property which tries to call `getSize()`, but there is no such method? I think you need to explictly call the `size()` method like this: `th:text="${markets.size()}"`

Comment: Using `${markets.size()}` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use property notation `th:text="${markets.size}"`, then Thymeleaf will search for a method `getSize()` on the `markets` attribute in the model. But there is no `getSize()` method, only `size()` method.

So use the method itself instead of using the property notation:

```
th:text="${markets.size()}"
```

Comment: This caught me by surprise. I have `List<Person> people = ...`, where `Person` is a JavaBean. When I use `th:text="${people.size}"`, I get the expected result - and no errors. This is in plain Thymeleaf (no Spring), in case that is a factor.

Comment: Ah, I always use Thymeleaf with Spring, so maybe there is a difference there indeed.