# Thymeleaf iterator th:each does not view information

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So, i write spring boot Controller, write Entity -> Course, write html views-> courses, but my information did not view in my template.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/courses")
public class CourseController {
    
    private CourseService courseService;
    public CourseController(CourseService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping ("/index")
    public String getCourses (Model model, @RequestParam (name="keyword", defaultValue = "") String keyword ) {
        List <Course> courses = courseService.findCourseBycourseName(keyword);
        model.addAttribute("listCourses", courses);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        return "views/courses";
        
    }
```

HTML + Thymeleaf courses.html -> when I start app loaded only empty table.

```
<tbody> 
<tr class ="text-center" th:each="course : ${listCourses}" > 
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseId()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseName()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseDuration()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseDescription()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getInstructor().getInstructorFirstName()} + '' + course.getInstructor().getInstructorLastName"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getListStudent().size()}"> </td>

</tbody>
</table>
```

There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class.  There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class. There is my Course Class.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "courses")
public class Course {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "course_id", nullable=false)
    private Long courseId;
    
    @Basic 
    @Column (name = "name", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseName;
    @Basic
    
    @Column (name = "duration", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseDuration;
    
    @Basic
    @Column (name = "description", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseDescription;
    
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name = "instructor_id", referencedColumnName = "instructor_id", nullable = false)
    private Instructor instructor;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable (name = "enrolled_in", 
                                     joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "course_id")}, 
                                     inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "student_id")})
    private Set<Student> listStudent = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(courseId, courseName, courseDuration, courseDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Course course = (Course) obj;
        return courseId.equals(course.courseId) && Objects.equals(courseName, course.courseName) && Objects.equals(courseDuration, course.courseDuration) && Objects.equals(courseDescription, course.courseDescription);
    }

    // add object student to the list students;
    // add course to the List of Students;
    public void assignStudentToCourse (Student student) {
        this.listStudent.add(student);
        student.getCourses().add(this);

    }
    
    // remove student from course
    
    public void removeStudents (Student students) {
        this.listStudent.remove(students);
        students.getCourses().remove(this);
    }
    

    public Course () {}
    
    public Course(String courseName, String courseDuration, String courseDescription, Instructor instructor) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }

    public Long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(Long courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseDuration() {
        return courseDuration;
    }

    public void setCourseDuration(String courseDuration) {
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }

    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }

    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }

    public Instructor getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }

    public Set<Student> getListStudent() {
        return listStudent;
    }

    public void setListStudent(Set<Student> listStudent) {
        this.listStudent = listStudent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [courseId=" + courseId + ", courseName=" + courseName + ", courseDuration=" + courseDuration
                + ", courseDescription=" + courseDescription + "]";
    }
}
```

Who knows where problem

Comment: Does the method `courseService.findCourseBycourseName()` return anything? Maybe check with a debugger if the `courses` list has items?

Comment: so i don know, how work this tutorials, but i change method  List <Course> courses = courseService.findCourseBycourseName(keyword) ---- > courseService.findAll(); and everything work good!

Comment: Can you paste your CourseService?

Comment: public interface CourseService {
 
 Course loadCourseBycourseId (Long courseId);
 
 Course createCourse (String courseName, String courseDuration, String courseDescription, Long instructorId);
 
 Course createOrUpdateCourse(Course course);
 
 List <Course> findCourseBycourseName(String keyword);
 
 void assignStudentToCourse (Long courseId, Long studentId);
 
 List <Course> fetchAll();
 
 List <Course> fetchCourseForstudentId (Long studentId);
 
 void removeCourse (Long courseId);

Comment: Could you help me, please, with that. My method fetchAll() show me this course, but i can not find, method findByCourseName did not show course, but i can find. I merge this method in Controller

@GetMapping ("/index")
 public String findCourse (Model model, RequestParam (name="keyword", defaultValue = "") String keyword ) {
  List <Course> courses = courseService.findCourseBycourseName(keyword);
  List <Course> course = courseService.fetchAll();
  model.addAttribute("listCourses", course);
  model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
  return "views/courses";
 }   and work method fetch

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your  tag in your HTML snippet.

```
<tbody> 
<tr class ="text-center" th:each="course : ${listCourses}" > 
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseId()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseName()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseDuration()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getCourseDescription()}"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getInstructor().getInstructorFirstName()} + '' + course.getInstructor().getInstructorLastName"> </td>
  <td th:text = "${course.getListStudent().size()}"> </td>
</tr><!-- bingo -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also see [How to print Array size in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484142/how-to-print-array-size-in-thymeleaf/43485872#43485872) because it might be your next question.

In your service class, make sure that you have `@Repository` as an annotation.  Each method name needs to reflect the property, in a case-sensitive camelCase format.  You should also rename it to `CourseRepository` to better describe what it is doing.  Note the difference:

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository <Course, Long> {

    Iterable<Course> findByCourseName(String courseName);

    //other ones    
    
    //CrudRepository will give you these two so you don't need to add them:
    //Iterable<Course> findAll();
    //Optional<Course> findById(Long courseId);    
}
```

You can look at `CrudRepository` or `JPARepository` to extend depending on your needs.  Info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring).

More modern design shows these queries returning with Java's `Optional` but this should not be the cause of your error.

(Also, in the future, you can just update the question with the code instead of commenting it.)

https://github.com/vphilipnyc/forvladislav

Comment: so i dont know, how work this tutorials, but i change method  List <Course> courses = courseService.findCourseBycourseName(keyword) ---- > courseService.findAll(); and everything work good!

Comment: Did you check the keyword you are providing?  What is returned if the service is given a null or empty string as the keyword?  For JPA repositories, you should also check that the method has the right case (e.g., "findCourseByCourseName" would be correct if the property is called courseName)

Comment: And you will still want to close that HTML tag since it is malformed.

Comment: Please could you help me with that. Why my List<Corse> did not view in application

Comment: If you are still having issues, update your question with the Course class too since that will describe how you have your properties set up.

Comment: I update and added Course class, if you can please help me solve this issues, tnx

Comment: https://github.com/vphilipnyc/forvladislav

Comment: Oh Big thanks!! these is real help me, solve my problem. You good It specialist